# How to setup a singleton broker in zeromq?

Tags: zeromq

I'm trying to design a system using ZeroMQ where I have a bunch of consumers that each want to use a service, and I need a way for the consumers to start the desired service if it's not started yet. I can visualize having a broker do this (useful to do so, since both consumers and service are dynamic, and their endpoints are TCP ports that can't be known before runtime), but then I have to figure out how to start the broker if it hasn't started yet.

How do you reliably start a single broker using ZeroMQ? The call to `bind()` seems to accept more than one socket.

Comment: "The call to bind() seems to accept more than one socket." -- hmm, not sure if this is a bug; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312101/why-does-jeromq-use-setreuseaddresstrue